# How to transfer some XAS to a Dapp with asch-cli

Tags: asch-development, asch, asch-cli

I've tried:

```
asch-cli -H 127.0.0.1 -P 4096 dapptransaction --secret "acquire paper fun spice celery design able shrimp lunch angry alter gather" --dapp 559ddee66bacb008f1a5eb2692ef18ba9b0d9da923989da4070c0fd33d0d3352 --args "{currency:'XAS',amount:5000000000}" --fee 10000000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comple documentation of `asch-cli` can be found at https://github.com/AschPlatform/asch-docs/blob/master/cli_usage/en.md. You should try to use to replace `dapptransaction` with `deposit`.

So try something like that shown below:

```
asch-cli -H 127.0.0.1 -P 4096 deposit --secret "" --dapp "" --currency "XAS" --amount 5000
```